# БЭМ стили, которые не меняются

Tags: css, классы, бэм

Есть ли смысл в таком коде, если тег `p` и все его содержимое имеет два стиля - `text-align:center; color: blue` :

```
<div class="block block_right">
    <p class="block__title block__title_blue">title 
       <span class="block__date block__date_blue">date</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Можно ли сделать так и задать ему два нужных стиля:

```
<div class="block block_right">
    <p class="block__text">title 
       <span>date</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Прочтите мануал по БЭМ, уже второй подобный вопрос от вас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смысл в модификаторах - модифицировать (как ни странно:)) существующий блок для его переиспользования в других местах. Поэтому если вы хотите сделать блок по умолчанию синим - это ваше право.

Если говорить о использовании первого варианта (с модификаторами), то следует правильно именовать (в данном случае правильнее использовать модификаторы "ключ-значение"):

```
<div class="block block_right">
    <p class="block__title block__title_color_blue">title 
       <span class="block__date block__date_color_blue">date</span>
    </p>
</div>
```